# Pythonic way to calling a private function recursively within a class

Tags: python, recursion

Today I've tried to call a private method recursively within a class:

```
class Bot:
    def __init__(self, sudoku):
        """ init code """

    def __findJokers(self, target):
        """ some validations """
        self.__findJokers(target)
```

Running my program, I've recived a:

```
{AttributeError}'Bot' object has no attribute '__findJokers'
```

Searching a while, I found that you can call a private function **outside** the class scope using the `instance._Bot__findJokers(somevalue)`

But, there is an other(or a better) way to call this private function **inside** the class?

Comment: @FabioBohnenberger Nope, that is the only way to do it. The process is called [name unmangling](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references)

Comment: I cannot reproduce that problem, are you sure your actual code doesn't differ from this?

Comment: Hum, okay! No problems with use `_Bot__findJokers`, it is just a little verbose :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like this if you're calling it from the outside:

```
class Bot:
    def __init__(self, sudoku):
        """ init code """
        pass

    # public access
    def findJokers(self, target):
        # forward to private
        return self.__findJokers(target)

    # private access
    def __findJokers(self, target):
        """ some validations """
        # hopefully you're doing something else,
        # since this is an infinite recursion.
        return self.__findJokers(target)
```

**Note:** You don't have to return anything.

Answer (score 0):

As a complement, if you wonder why the `__findJokers` method is only accessible from inside the class methods, this is how it works:

```
>>> dir(Bot)
['_Bot__findJokers', '__doc__', '__init__', '__module__']
```

The `__findJokers` has been renamed `_Bot_findJokers` in the internal class dictionary.

Then let's disassembly the method.

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(Bot._Bot__findJokers)
 17           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (_Bot__findJokers)
[...]
```

The attribute name is also replaced with `_Bot_findJokers` directly in the method code.
Also observable here:

```
>>> Bot._Bot__findJokers.im_func.func_code.co_names
('_Bot_findJokers',)
```

Meaning that in the end, the attribute `__findJokers` never really existed.